# Salesforce SOQL query not returning rows when LastModifiedDate is compared to two dates

Tags: date, salesforce, between, soql

and thanks for taking the time to look at my post.

I am trying to retrieve a list of contacts modified between two dates (LastModifiedDate >= Date1 AND LastModifiedDate <= Date2). When I query  I receive 0 rows. If I take out ONLY the second part (LastModifiedDate <= Date2) I receive many.

Here is my code and the debug log - first with the two dates:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.parse('10/05/2011 00:00 AM');
DateTime myLastDate = DateTime.valueOf('2012-02-7 05:04:25');
System.debug('the first date:' + String.valueOf(myDate) + ' and the last date: ' + String.valueOf(myLastDate));
List<Contact> cList = [select id, FirstName, LastName, LastModifiedDate  FROM Contact WHERE Email <> '' AND Email <> null AND LastModifiedDate >= :myDate and lastModifiedDate <= :myLastDate];
system.debug('num cons' + cList.size());
```

debug

```
19:19:14.042 (42468000)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|the first date:2011-10-05 00:00:00 and the last date: 2012-02-07 05:04:25
19:19:14.042 (42478000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[3]|System.debug(ANY)
19:19:14.042 (42682000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[4]|Aggregations:0|select id, FirstName, LastName, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact  WHERE  Email <> '' AND Email <> null  AND LastModifiedDate >= :myDate and lastModifiedDate <= :myLastDate
19:19:18.055 (4055043000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[4]|Rows:0
```

and now with one date

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.parse('10/05/2011 00:00 AM');
DateTime myLastDate = DateTime.valueOf('2012-02-7 05:04:25');
System.debug('the first date:' + String.valueOf(myDate) + ' and the last date: ' + String.valueOf(myLastDate));
List<Contact> cList = [select id, FirstName, LastName, LastModifiedDate  FROM Contact WHERE  Email <> '' AND Email <> null   AND LastModifiedDate >= :myDate ];
system.debug('num cons' + cList.size());
```

debug:

```
19:20:55.039 (39038000)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|the first date:2011-10-05 00:00:00 and the last date: 2012-02-07 05:04:25
19:20:55.039 (39045000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[3]|System.debug(ANY)
19:20:55.039 (39249000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[4]|Aggregations:0|select id, FirstName, LastName, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact   WHERE  Email <> '' AND Email <> null  AND LastModifiedDate >= :myDate
19:21:06.555 (11555339000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[4]|Rows:21784
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I just tried your query as is against my org and got back rows. Are you sure you actually have Contacts that fall within that date range?

Comment: @rbrainard Yes - please see the debug. The later date is the current date (or was when I ran the query). When I run it in batches of 500, the first couple thousand are all on that first date.

Comment: I just wanted to also confirm that I can take your first block of code, run it 'as is' in the Force.com console, and get data back. Your debug for one date shows there are rows after the first date but how many rows are returned if you run it for all rows modified before the "current" date? Try running it with the other date only and see what happens.

Comment: @RyanElkins I get back more than the 50,000 limit. BUT I JUST TRIED THIS AGAIN (FOR THE 1000TH TIME) AND IT WORKED. THANKS FOR YOUR TIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just started working without any changes on my end.

Thanks everyone for your help.